# How to check a point is on one side of a plane(or planes)?

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm

[image: Pic1]

Please take a look at pic1 above first. 
2 points combine a line, let's call it LineAB, and we can get a normal from our eye sight direction, let's call it view-direction, vector(lineAB) X view-direction, we can get a normal named plane-normal. in the pic1, plane-normal is directed to the top (green arrow), and the plane with plane-normal cut the map into 2 parts.

As the point C is on the same direction of the plane-normal, we regard it as inside, let's return true. Point D is on the anti-direction of plane-normal, it is outside, return false.

My problem is in the pic2 as following:
[image: Pic2]

Now, there are many points A,A1,A2...A5,... An, build many lines such as lineAA1, line A1A2, ... LineAn-1An (one condition is: every angle between 2 adjacent lines are equal to or more than 90 degree) and plus with view direction (the direction from our eye sight), we can get many planes PAA1, PA1P2, ... PAn-1An which also cut the map to 2 parts.

I need to check one point is inside or outside. 
for example, point C is inside but point D is outside.

Comment: Is it possible, that your `A1..An` points will produce a polygon? If yes, then can it be self-intersected? Or may be even many polygons? Are complex cases, such as one point inside first polygon and another is inside second polygon, e t.c. ?

Answer (score 2):

Regarding one plane **separating the dim(3)-space** isn't difficult, to consider a piecewise assembled dim(2)-plane we need to dive deeper:

The problem may be reduced to **separating the dim(2)-space**.
If only for the calculation of the normal the 3rd dimension is considered, then that can solved in a different way:
Let v = (a,b) be the vector of a lineAB. The normal is (b, -a) or (-b, a) respectively.

If you want to check only if a point is *within* a polygon, just use the ray-casting-algorithm.

When it comes to dividing the dim(2)-space into two separate spaced by your polygonal chain, it won't be enough to check if the point is on the positive directon of the normals on each part line(A[i-1])(A[i]):

**Polygonal chain**
[image: polygonal-chain]
*Point P* is positive with respect to normal N0, but negative w.r.t. normal N1.
Also, the upper angles are all above 90° (some counter angles are also displayed), but the polygon chain isn't convex either w.r.t. the upward y-axis.
To solve your issue, you can use the **ray-casting-algorithm**, going **towards negative y-direction**, i.e. "downwards", and see if  the amount of intersections is odd.

- If the line *ends at a higher x-coordinate* than the start point, an odd amount of intersections means "true"
- If the line *ends at a lower x-coordinate* than the start point, an odd amount of intersections means "false"

Answer (score 0):

You can find if a ray from point C (with view direction) intersects with one of the segments AiAi+1. It could be done with binary search by X-coordinate (to find potential segment quickly)